# my nodejs error width Cannot read property data of undefined

Tags: node.js

my nodejs service always output this error : Cannot read property data of undefined, not only get data from other services ,but also query the db ,so please give me some suggestions,thanks;

Comment: please show your code, show your efforts.

Comment: Please paste your code, but this error happens may because of wrong context of 'this'. If it caused by wrong context, you should use bind, call or apply to indicate the this context.

Comment: 1. Always defined variables.
2. Don't find value of not exist key in json

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the entire error that you quoted as "Cannot read property data of undefined" then you'll see that it includes the file name and line number. In that line you will see something like `x.data` and this error means that the `x` is undefined. If you add a `console.log` or other logging to that line and you'll try to print the `x` (or whatever name it is in your case) then you'll see that it is indeed undefined just before you get the error, contrary to what you described here.